# 3D Animation with CSS/javascripts

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Could someone please help with the code below.  I tried to follow instructions from this link to create a horizontal infinite photo wheel.  http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/infinite-photo-carousel/

There are several things going wrong with this:

1) When hovering over any image, the images disappear
2) After awhile, it continues to rotate but half (or more) of the visible images are no longer visible
3) The border around the center picture rotates with the picture, then is supposed to move back to the center but on the next picture in sequence.  It looks like the code is moving the picture AND the border back.
4) Major problems trying to view in IE.  I wrote this in Chrome and I am at least getting 3D success. IE is showing the first 5 images flat and no animation. I need this to work in IE, Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Code attached

```css
 <style type="text/css">

  #stage3 {
    margin: 2em auto 1em 50%;
    height: 140px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
        -moz-perspective: 1200px;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
            -ms-perspective: 1200px;
    -ms-perspective-origin: 0 50%;
  }
    #rotator3 a {
    position: absolute;
    left: -81px;
    -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
  }
  #rotator3 a img {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ffff00;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
    #rotator3 a:nth-of-type(1) img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(300px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(300px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(300px);
  }
  #rotator3 a:nth-of-type(2) img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-60deg) translateZ(300px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-60deg) translateZ(300px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-60deg) translateZ(300px);
  }
  #rotator3 a:nth-of-type(3) img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(300px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(300px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(300px);
  }
  #rotator3 a:nth-of-type(4) img {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(300px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(300px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(300px);
    background: #ffff00;
  }
  #rotator3 a:nth-of-type(5) img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(300px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(300px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(300px);
  }
  #rotator3 a:nth-of-type(6) img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(300px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(300px);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(300px);
  }
  #rotator3 a:nth-of-type(n+7) img { display: none; }
  
    @-webkit-keyframes rotator3 {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);}
  }
    @-moz-keyframes rotator3 {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    to   { -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg);}
  }
    @-ms-keyframes rotator3 {
    from { -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);}
    to   { -ms-transform: rotateY(30deg);}
  }
    #rotator3 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
    -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  

  </style>

<div id="stage3">
<div id="rotator3" style="-webkit-animation-name: rotator3;-moz-animation-name: rotator3;">
<a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
  <a href="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg"><img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rp9x78.jpg" width="140"></a>
<a href="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg"><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/30rpow7.jpg" width="140"></a>
</div>
</div>
  
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Original JavaScript code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var rotateComplete = function(e) {
      with(target.style) {
        webkitAnimationName = MozAnimationName = msAnimationName = "";
      }
      target.insertBefore(arr[arr.length - 1], arr[0]);
      setTimeout(function(el) {
        with(el.style) {
          webkitAnimationName = MozAnimationName = msAnimationName = "rotator3";
        }
      }, 0, target);
    };

    var target = document.getElementById("rotator3");
    var arr = target.getElementsByTagName("a");

    target.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", rotateComplete, false);
    target.addEventListener("animationend", rotateComplete, false);
    target.addEventListener("MSAnimationEnd", rotateComplete, false);

  }, false);

</script>
```

:

Comment: osx chrome 38.0.2125.122 is experiencing at least the first 2 issues you listed on the example link you provided. It appears the example code is broken to begin with?

Comment: Please try to minify the problem into something smaller